# Jackson serialization: String field containing regex expression de-escaping to get actual literal

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a DTO containing a field of type `String` which contains a regex expression. To be a valid Java string, it contains double `\` because the first one is used for escaping, which is easy to understand. Like:

```java
    private final String regex = "myapp\\.\\w{2,3}\\/confirmation(.*)";
```

The actual regex to use is `myapp\.\w{2,3}\/confirmation(.*)`.

And, I will send this DTO in a Kafka message, and the serialization is done by Jackson.

```java
ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>(
    kafkaTopicProperties.getTopic(),
    String.valueOf(myDto.getOrderId()),
    objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myDto)
);
```

Understandably, Jackson cannot distinguish normal string and regex string, and will send the Java string escaped as-is. Additionally, it is also invalid to omit the escaping in JSON(at least when I edit a `.json` file to delete the escaping `\`, IntelliJ shows parsing error), so for a valid JSON, I also need to escape it. Normal till now.

But then, the consumer of Kafka will received a escaped regex string, and will have to de-escape the regex(removing the extra `\`). Here comes the problem. A syntatic change results in semantic difference.

Actually because Kafka has no limitations over what to send,  we are free to de-escape before sending because it would be plain text.

But, can Jackson do this magic for me?

Comment: The context (everything before the last sentence) is not necessary to your question, which is “can Jackson do this magic?”. What magic, *exactly*? Also a minor point, forward slashes do not need escaping - they have no special regex meaning, so just `myapp\.\w{2,3}/confirmation(.*)` is the same.

Comment: I mean, can Jackson by some annotation/whatever, get to know that this string is a regex, and serialize the string as a valid regex, removing the extra `\\` for me?

Comment: Don't include the extra `\\`, send the actual RegEx in your JSON

Comment: Hm.. about `/`, https://regex101.com/ shows me an error of pattern if I remove the "\" before `/`.

Comment: Jackson doesn't send the escaped string as is, your logic is wrong. When you write the string on the code you escape it, but in memory Java retains a non-escaped version of the string. The reasons why it is escaped in the JSON is because Jackson re-escape the string because it is required by the JSON format.

Comment: If Kafka read the JSON properly it should know that it has to unescape every strings, and so I don't see where is your problem.

Comment: Ah... @NyamiouTheGaleanthrope that is something very valid. Could I avoid this re-escaping somehow? By stopping serializing it into a JSON, but to a plain text, maybe?

Comment: So you mean I am worrying too much and that problem will not exist for consumer? Good to know that.

Comment: Whether it’s regex or not is irrelevant. A string is a string. In your case, it’s `myapp\.\w{2,3}/confirmation(.*)`. Json, like java, requires backslashes to be escaped because the backslash is itself the escape character. When Kafka deserialises the string from json, it needs to respect backslash as the json escape character. The problem seems to be that Kafka doesn’t do that. The fix is not to change your code is any way. Kafka is where the problem lies - you need to fix the way it parses json. Perhaps it is treating the json as a string and not json. If so, you need to fix that.

Comment: @WesternGun regex101 is not java. Some languages/tools use the forward slash as a regex *delimiter*, so in that context forward slashes need escaping when writing the regex in code. But not in java and not anywhere in the final regex.

Comment: @NyamiouTheGaleanthrope now I see that I receive the Kafka message does not de-escape my string, so here is what the problem lies.

Comment: @Bohemian yes you are right. It checks regex, not Java-specific regex syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @Bohemian and @NyamiouTheGaleanthrope

Indeed as you said, I think I have found the problem: the deserializer should be `org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer` in the `Consumer`, and in the producer, the serializer should be `org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer`. Then all is good, I can see in the log that the regex has no extra escape char. I was using `String(De)Serializer` before.

Configs for both sides put together:

`application.yml`:

```yaml
spring:
  kafka:
    producer:
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
    consumer: # would be picked if you autowired the consumer
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
      properties.spring.json.trusted.packages: '*'
```

Producer:

```java
ProducerRecord<String, OrderMessageDto> record = new ProducerRecord<>(
    kafkaTopicProperties.getTopic(),
    String.valueOf(orderDto.getId()),
    orderDto
);
kafkaTemplateOrder.send(record).get(kafkaTopicProperties.getTimeout(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Consumer(I only have a consumer in test, so I have to configure by hand):

```java
    @Autowired
    private EmbeddedKafkaBroker kafkaBroker;

    ...


    private ConsumerRecords consumeRecords(String topic) {
        Map<String, Object> consumerProps = KafkaTestUtils.consumerProps(topic, "true", kafkaBroker);
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        JsonDeserializer<OrderPaymentUrlDto> valueDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>();
        valueDeserializer.addTrustedPackages("*"); // necessary for include DTO as trusted type
        ConsumerFactory<String, OrderPaymentUrlDto> factory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
                consumerProps,
                new StringDeserializer(),
                valueDeserializer
        );
        Consumer consumer = factory.createConsumer();
        kafkaBroker.consumeFromAnEmbeddedTopic(consumer, topic);
        return KafkaTestUtils.getRecords(consumer, 2000);
    }
```